# Repetition of rows in VB6

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vb6

I am importing the data from SQL Server using VB6 and displaying it in a Grid. The Grid has 100 rows and when I try to populate a single row from the database in a single row of the Grid, it repeats itself in the Grid 100 times but I only want it to stay in a single row. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
While Count < 100
    Dim adoCSRS As adodb.Recordset
    Set adoCSRS = New adodb.Recordset
    adoCSRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    'Then comes my query which has no problem as the data is being retrieved without any problem and then'

    Dim i As Integer

    While Not adoCSRS.EOF


        'After this part, I assign the text fields their respective values from Database and then'

        i = i + 1

        MSFlexGrid.AddItem _
        adoCSRS.Fields("Coulmn Name") & Chr(9) & _
        adoCSRS.Fields("Coulmn Name") & Chr(9) & _
        adoCSRS.Fields("Coulmn Name") & Chr(9) & _
        adoCSRS.Fields("Coulmn Name") & Chr(9) & _
        adoCSRS.Fields("Coulmn Name") & Chr(9) & _
        adoCSRS.Fields("Coulmn Name") & Chr(9) & _
        adoCSRS.Fields("Coulmn Name") & Chr(9)

        MSFlexGrid.Col = 11
        MSFlexGrid.Row = i
        MSFlexGrid.CellFontName = "Wingdings"
        MSFlexGrid.CellFontSize = 10
        MSFlexGrid.CellAlignment = flexAlignCenterCenter
        MSFlexGrid.TextMatrix(i, 14) = uncheckedBox

        adoCSRS.MoveNext
    Wend

    MSFlexGrid.RowSel = 0
    successful = True

    Count = Count + 1
Wend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two separate (not nested) while loops. The first loop adds the data from the database. The second loop adds empty rows to the grid:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
While Not adoCSRS.EOF
  i = i + 1
  ' Add from db - same as your code above '
  MSFlexGrid.AddItem _
    adoCSRS.Fields("Coulmn Name") _
    ...
Wend

While i < 100
  i = i + 1
  ' Add blank row '
  MSFlexGrid.AddItem _
    ...
Wend
```

Comment: I know. I want to show 100 rows in the grid but I don't want the fields extracted from database to show in all of those 100 rows.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'll let you know by tomorrow :)

Comment: Okay this works fine. But what if there are 2 rows being extracted from database and I want to display it in the first 2 and keep rest of the 98 empty and so on so forth till 100 rows are extracted from database and none of the rows in Grid are left empty?

Comment: I figured out a way. Thank you.